# Can't sftp into server in Mint

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, sftp

This isn't my strongest suit. I have tried multiple fft/sftp programs in Mint, and I cannot sftp (ssh) into the server. I have the exact same settings in xubuntu on another machine and it hooks up immediately. I now have a bare bones sftp program called barefft installed on both machines. There isn't a lot of settings:
Host: rahs.net
Login name
password:
port 22
SSH(SFTP)

Like I said, it works in xubuntu, but not in Mint. I've also tried Filezilla, but I couldn't get that to work in either of them, though it worked fine in Debian. Is there something that different amongst these variants of Debian? Anyway, any ideas on what I could be doing wrong. Mint 4.9.3

Update: I did find that I can easily SFTP into the server in Terminal, so I guess my issue is that none of the graphical ftp programs are working for me in the Mint XFCE environment.